# Oracle returning multiple recordset

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cursor, multiple-resultsets

How can i return multiple record set from a procedure without using cursor.I'm using cursor often for my query, as you know cursor tired system.Is there any way getting multiple data?

Comment: Yes, a procedure can return record set using out parameters.

Comment: Please be more specific, with some examples.

Comment: @Lesya, you can definitely return cursors.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  You can write a procedure that has multiple `OUT` parameters of type `SYS_REFCURSOR`.  It seems unlikely that this is a great approach but without understanding the business problem you're trying to solve, it's hard to guess what a more appropriate technical implementation might be.  I'm not sure what you mean when you say "cursor tired system"

Comment: Maybe the question is from SQL Server world, where sp could return multiply recordsets? In oracle we use cursors for that.